# multinomial Naive Bayes: how to calculate likelihood and posterior?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, naive-bayes

For a multinomial Naive Bayes model for $C$ classes and $D$ features, assuming $\theta \in \mathcal{R}^{C x D}$ is the matrix whose $\theta_{cj} $ element corresponds to $Prob(x_j = 1 | y= c)$, and $\pi \in \mathcal{R}^C$ is the class prior probability.

1) The likelihood for a training example $(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)})$ can be written as :

Likelihood = $P(x^{(i)}, y^{(i)} =c | \theta, \pi) = P(x^{(i)} | y^{(i)}=c; \theta )  \hspace{3pt} P(y^{(i)} = c | \pi) = \big(\prod_{j=1}^{D} \theta_{jc}^{\mathbb{I}(x^{(i)}_j=1)} \big) \pi_c
$

2) On the other hand, the posterior prediction for a new training example $(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$ can be written as:

Posterior = $ P(\tilde{y}=c | \tilde{x}; \theta, \pi ) = \dfrac{ P(\tilde{x} | \tilde{y}=c;\theta) P(\tilde{y}=c | \pi)}{P( \tilde{x} | \theta, \pi)} = \dfrac{P(\tilde{x} | \tilde{y}=c;\theta) P(\tilde{y}=c | \pi)}{ \sum_{c'} P(\tilde{x} | \tilde{y}=c';\theta) P(\tilde{y}=c' | \pi) }$

**Question**:
In terms of the formalism, the main difference in the calculations of the likelihood and the posterior is the normalization factor, $P( x | \theta, \pi)$. Does it make a difference in practical calculation?

Looking at [scikit-learn implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/naive_bayes.py), it seems that it doesn't make a distinction.